# PHP - strpos on array elements?

Tags: php, loops, search, strpos

For some reason I can't get strpos to work to search my array, even if `$jobList[1]` and `$titlesearch` are the same values... Sorry if it's something obvious but I'm still pretty new to coding!

I begin with my `$data` array which looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => P0001    Lifeguard   descexample 18/09/18    parttime    fixedterm       mail    vic

    [2] => P0002    IT Manager  descexample 18/09/18    fulltime    ongoing post    mail    sa

)
```

I then explode each of these entries into their own array...

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
    $jobList = explode("\t", $data[$i]);
}

Array
(
    [0] => P0001
    [1] => Lifeguard
    [2] => descexample  
    [3] => 18/09/18
    [4] => parttime
    [5] => fixedterm
    [6] => 
    [7] => mail
    [8] => vic

)
Array
(
    [0] => P0002
    [1] => IT Manager
    [2] => descexample  
    [3] => 18/09/18
    [4] => fulltime
    [5] => ongoing
    [6] => post
    [7] => mail
    [8] => sa

)
```

Now I'm trying to search through these arrays from a user input, `$titlesearch`, and find it's matches with the job titles, `$jobList[1]`:

```
if (strpos($jobList[1], $titlesearch)) {
        echo "nice one";
    }
```

No matter what loops I try, the `strpos` never returns true, even if I echo the values and they both give the same result, so I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong :'(

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's because strpos doesn't return a boolean value. It returns the position in the substring was found (which may be 0) or -1 if not found.

Comment: `$jobList = explode("\t", $data[$i]);`->don't you think you are overwriting the values. you will not get the second array into that variable.

Comment: @Vince0789 `strpos` can return a __boolean__ value. But it __never__ returns -1, this is not javascript.

Comment: @u_mulder ah yes, you're right. The return value is boolean false if the substring is not found, however the function may also return 0 if the substring was found at the start of the string, so the comparison should still be carried out with the identical operator (===).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always compare the data type when using this function as it may not return a **boolean** and it can be missleading.  [Check documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Try it something like this:

```
if (strpos($jobList[1], $titlesearch) !== false) {
        echo "nice one";
}
```

Comment: Yay! This explains why it worked when I was messing around with it the other day too!

Thankyou very much :)